# getting the count of user inputs and using it to get the average in java

Tags: java, if-statement, input, while-loop, count

I have the following code in java:

```
public void userControlledLoop()
{
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int total = 0;
    int count = 0;
    
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    int number = reader.nextInt();
    total += number;
    
    System.out.println("Would you like to enter another number type y or n: ");
    String answer = reader.next();

    while (answer != "n")
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        number = reader.nextInt();
        total += number;
        
        System.out.println("Would you like to enter another number type y or n: ");
        answer = reader.next();
        
        if (answer != "y")
        {
            System.out.println("Goodbye");
            break;
        }
    }
    // Only thing missing from here is the average. In order to work out the average 
    // i need to keep track of the number of inputs and then divide the total by that
    count++;
    System.out.println(total);
}
```

My main goal is to ask the user to enter a number of their choice and then ask the user if they want to input another number. The user must reply with "y" or "n".

Each time the user enters their number it is added to the total variable so i can later use it to work out the average.

I also have a count variable which is intended to keep track of the users input by incrementation (i saw in another stack question). However, this does not work and the function breaks after only 2 iterations.

I am trying to get some advice on how i could make the code work or if people recommend i start from scratch.

Comment: Also, `count++` is in the wrong place. Think about what it should do